# Insert UIIMageView at Index:0

Tags: iphone

How would you insert it behind the main view?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertSubview:belowSubview:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:belowSubview:)

```
[mainView.superview insertSubview:imageView belowSubview:mainView];
```